# Using vulkan API on Android for computing genetic algorithm

Tags: cluster-computing, hardware, vulkan

So ive been pondering with this idea.

Is there any worth investigating using vulkan API to compute some genetic algorithm and make some Beowulf cluster out of cheapo Android phone and/or TV box and/or computers and/or laptop. The idea is to bring this to the poor and so people can have "super computing" power for relatively cheap. I see this brought in classroom with low budget and etc.

You would require a master mode with a DB and all the devices gets pushed a stack of instructions to compute using vulkan and push back results.

Is the vulkan API good for this?? Problem is I want it to be able to scale so that you can run any kind of device and all of them can just be plugged in through the Ethernet port, contact the server and start working.

Comment: Most of the challenges with something like this are going to be around building/maintaining/scheduling a cluster, and around designing an algorithm that runs efficiently on a GPU, rather than which GPU compute API (Vulkan, OpenGL, OpenCL, CUDA, etc.) you use.

Answer (score 2):

Vulkan is primarily **graphics** rendering API.
It does have a compute shader capability, but it is meant more of as a convenience to avoid the dificulty of interoperation with OpenCL for some computational subtask for your graphics app.

OpenCL is a compute API and probably what you want/need.
OpenCL predates Vulkan and so possibly even has higher amount of supported devices.

Unless you need rasterizing triangles on a 2D surface, there is a chance you do not want Vulkan as your primary choice for your problem.

Comment: I don't have the requirements to upvote you guys but thank you for the help! I'll definitely keep looking deeper.

Answer (score 0):

- [A simple Vulkan Compute example](http://www.duskborn.com/posts/a-simple-vulkan-compute-example/)
- [Erkaman/vulkan_minimal_compute](https://github.com/Erkaman/vulkan_minimal_compute)